# Crear List sin datos repetidos

Tags: flutter, dart

Como vemos, en ambas listas se repiten dos horas. Me gustaría saber cómo hacer que en la Lista final salgan solo los que no se repiten en ambas listas como a continuación:

```
List1["10:00:00","10:40:00","11:20:00"]
List2["10:40:00","11:20:00","12:00:00"]

List3["10:00:00","12:00:00"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que las Lista es de `String` podrías usar lo siguiente:

Crea una tercera lista para los resultados no duplicados, manteniendo las listas originales intactas.
Al final puedes iterar el HashMap para extraer los valores únicos de las listas. Puedes crear una lista de listas en el caso que tengas mas de dos listas e iterar una sola lista.

```
List<String> List3 = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

checkList(hmap, List1);
checkList(hmap, List2);
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : hmap.entrySet()) {
    List3.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

Creas un método para las listas, remover los valores es necesario por si hay `Strings` que se repiten mas de dos veces:

```
public static void checkList(HashMap<String, Integer> hmap, List<String> List) {
    for (String str : List) {
        if (!hmap.containsKey(str)) {
            hmap.put(str, hmap.getOrDefault(str, 0) + 1);
        } else {
            hmap.put(str, hmap.getOrDefault(str, 0) - 1);
            if (hmap.get(str) <= 0) hmap.remove(str);
        }
    }
}
```